# make a phone call click on a button

Tags: android, button, phone-call

I'm trying to make a call when I press a button in android

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    String phno="10digits";

    Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse(phno));
    startActivity(i);
  }
});
```

But when I run and click on the button it gives me the error

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1021): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=9392438004 }
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you try this on emulator? Try on the real phone. Emulator may miss the caller activity.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Have you given the permission in the manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

and inside your activity

```
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Let me know if you find any issue.

Comment: There is absolutely no issues at all. Wow!!! I am just learning to write apps for Android now and this question was asked back in 2011. Thank you for this short and sweet answer.

Comment: You should not use Intent.ACTION_CALL unless you are writing a dialer app. Instead you should use Intent.ACTION_DIAL which prepopulates the dialer with the number you pass it. The proper fix for the problem is to just prepend "tel:" in front of the 10 digits number you want to call.

Comment: **10 digits**? so you can't call a mobile with international prefix, like +491702112334? because this is **13 digits**

Comment: I know this is old but im doing stuff for old hardware. 
Im getting the "No Activity Found" exception  on the android 2,1 (api 7) platform. Is there a way to dial from this platform?

Comment: No need to add permission when using ACTION_DIAL

Answer (score 16):

> There are two intents to call/start calling: ACTION_CALL and ACTION_DIAL.

`ACTION_DIAL` will only open the `dialer with the number` filled in, but allows the user to actually c`all or reject the call`. `ACTION_CALL` will immediately call the number and **requires an extra permission**.

> So make sure you have the permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
```

in your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dbm.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- NOTE! Your uses-permission must be outside the "application" tag
               but within the "manifest" tag. -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Insert your other stuff here -->

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: hi,i have a question regarding this answer.If i have to make call to an international phone number,then where should i mention the country code?

Comment: I don't have access to this code anymore. Sorry but it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132724/checking-if-call-being-made-is-international

Answer (score 13):

None of the above worked so with a bit of tinkering here's code that did for me

```
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        String p = "tel:" + getString(R.string.phone_number);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(p));
        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 12):

change your String to `String phno="tel:10digits";` and try again.

Comment: thanks Harshad but i can't get any key pad it can directly call to that number without user modification of that number

Comment: You want to call directly without showing dial pad??? if so then use `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(phno));`

Comment: Calling directly as above will not work unless and untill you add this line as child of your manifest in manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>`

Comment: did this think worked? You can accept the answer and help others if it is correct..

Comment: how directly make a video call to particular phone no provided in tel:10digit no,duo video call from android pleae help me.

Answer (score 8):

I was having a hell of a time with this as well. I didn't realize that beyond the extra permission you need to append "tel:" onto the string that has the number in it. This is what mine looks like after getting it functional. Hope this helps.

```js
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
  String temp = "tel:" + phone;
  intent.setData(Uri.parse(temp));

  startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Helpful @JCrooks , mostly users don't allow permissions    and this will help in that scenario.

Answer (score 5):

check permissions before (for android 6 and above):

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) ==
                            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) 
   {

     context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:09130000000")));
   }
```

Answer (score 4):

add "tel:" along with your number to be dialed in your intent and then start your activity.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 String phNum = "tel:" + "1234567890";
 myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phNum));
  startActivity( myIntent ) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

To have the code within one line, try this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789")));
```

along with the proper manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

For those using AppCompact...Try this

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.net.Uri;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.db);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                makeCall();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void makeCall() {
        EditText num = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Dail);
        String phone = num.getText().toString();
        String d = "tel:" + phone ;
        Log.i("Make call", "");
        Intent phoneIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        phoneIntent.setData(Uri.parse(d));
        try {
            startActivity(phoneIntent);
            finish();
            Log.i("Finished making a call", "");
        } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Call faild, please try again later.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Then add this to your manifest,,,

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Also good to check is telephony supported on device

```
private boolean isTelephonyEnabled(){
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
return tm != null && tm.getSimState()==TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I hope, this short code is useful for You,
   ## Java Code ##
 startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:"+txtPhn.getText().toString())));



----------------------------------------------------------------------


Please check Manifest File,(for Uses permission)
## Manifest.xml ##
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.dbm.pkg"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- NOTE! Your uses-permission must be outside the "application" tag
               but within the "manifest" tag. -->
## uses-permission for Making Call ##
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Insert your other stuff here -->

    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved the problem on an Android 4.0.2 device (GN) and the only version working for this device/version was similar to the first 5-starred with CALL_PHONE permission and the answer:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

With any other solution i got the ActivityNotFoundException on this device/version.
How about the older versions? Would someone give feedback?

Answer (score 0):

```
Button customercare_call=findViewById(R.id.customercare_call); 
 customercare_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String phone = "Mobile Number";
            Intent intent = new  Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));    
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

With permission:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:9875432100"));
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(yourActivity.this,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(yourActivity.this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)) {
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(yourActivity.this,
                            new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CALL_PHONE);
                }
            }
startActivity(callIntent);
```