# Phone Call On TextView Click

Tags: android

How to make a phone call in android when user Click on textView then automatically dail a number in textView ?

```
  TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_contact);
 String url = tv.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));

 tv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });'
```

Comment: Check out answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403308/make-a-phone-call-click-on-a-button

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Add permission to call in AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

First make your TextView clickable by adding below in your layout.xml

```
<TextView 
...
...
android:clickable="true">
</TextView>
```

Then in your Activity Class, inside OnClickListener of that particular TextView add below code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 22) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MoreProgramDetailActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 101);

            return;
        }
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + tv.getText().toString().trim()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
 } else {

        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+" + tv.getText().toString().trim()));
        startActivity(callIntent);
 }
```

Comment: Use `"tel:"` without the `+` sign to dial local numbers. Also requires the `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` permission.