# Checking if call being made is international

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-call

I'd like to check if a call being made is international or not. I have the SIM number which I obtain by using TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() and also the Country code ISO of the SIM Card which I obtain using TelephonyManager.getSimCountryIso().

Is there anyway I can find the country code of the number to which the call is being made?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `telephonyManager.getSimCountryIso()` would help you determine 'to which country the call is being made' as it will return **your** country's ISO.

Moreover, length of ISD codes vary across countries. For some countries it is 1, for some it's 2, for some it's 3 and for others it's 4. So you will need to extract/make 4 different keys of these lengths from the outgoing number as I have shown below:

Say the out going number is +91-XXX-XXX-XXXX.
then you'll create 4 keys as:

1. **9**    (1 digit key)
2. **91**   (2 digit key)
3. **91X**  (3 digit key)
4. **91XX** (4 digit key)

Now check if any of these 4 keys is present in this list: [ISO List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_country_calling_codes#Complete_listing).

**[EDIT: Alternative Solution]**

Again, if you only need to determine if the call being made is international or not then you can simply check for below condition:

```
if(outgoing-number `startswith` "00" || outgoing-number does not `startswith` your "country's-ISD-code") {
    //it's an international call;
} else {
    //it's a domestic call;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but then was wondering if this'd be the best possible way forward, because what I have in the ISO list is a huge number of entires and checking it against all the entries in the ISO List may not be feasible. All I need to determine is to check if the call is international. So basically, now that I have the Originating Conuntry Code ISO i need to compare it with the one to which the call is being made.. Is there anyway any function call would return the country code ISO of the number provided?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please see if it answers your query.

Comment: Seems good. But however, when I dial a number I need not enter my country code each time right unless it is an International call. Say, I dial a mobile number which just begins with 944 or with 0944 if it is a outstation one or even a landline number 080-something, I need not enter the country code in the beginning.. In this case I cant check if it starts with my country code, because it may not be giving me the correct result. Please do correct me if I'm wrong or if there is something I'm missing out on.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I have modified my answer further. Please check.

Comment: I guess that should do it.. However, we could maybe add just 1 more 'if' condition within the international call part wherein we check if the characters following the '00' is not the same as the home country code. Just incase someone enters 0091 followed by the number and the home country code is 91, then the call still proceeds, n i assume this wouldnt be considered as an international call..

Comment: Absolutely. Well, there you go.. your logic seems to be ready now. :)