# Button's onClick() not getting called

Tags: android, buttonclick

I am trying to make a call button whereby when a user clicks on a button, it makes a phone call.

Now I have the Radio Button and the code for the button but when clicked it does nothing.

I already have the `CALL_PHONE` and `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions set in the manifest but still not working when the button is pressed.

Here is my code for the radio button in the activity:

```
Button radioButton;
call();


radioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
}

private void call()
{
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("0000000000"));
    try{
        startActivity(in);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699819/how-do-i-get-the-dialer-to-open-with-phone-number-displayed

Comment: From what you posted, you never seem to call the "call method".

Comment: what error you got runtime permissions?

Comment: no error, it just does not run when pressed.

Comment: vincenth, how would you advice me to fix this.

Comment: whats your android OS version ? 6.0?

Comment: Something along these lines : radioButon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        call();

    }
});

Comment: android version OS 4.4

Comment: vincenth, i already tried that to no avail. where should i code that that line? maybe i am wrong there.

Comment: Is there any error message in your logs ?

Comment: If you've **Instant Run** enabled, better disable it and then run. It's still broken and hinders development. If it still doesn't work, it will be a better idea to share the code where you're calling that method.

Comment: Check my answer on similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236504/no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-with-action-dial/16236670#16236670. I believe Uri.parse need "tel" prefix

Comment: are you set permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" /> ???

Comment: no errors in the logs. it just doesn't want to work. when user clicks button, it does nothing

Comment: SO i saw my error, i fixed it by changing the ACTION_CALL to ACTION_DIAL because of checkPermission and security feature on android. so original code works. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are not calling the Call method on radio button click. Here is the Workaround of your problem.

**First Way:**

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
               call();
} });
```

And Call your Method like this as you are doing

```
private void call(){
    Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("0000000000"));
    try{
        startActivity(in);
    }
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"yourActivity is not founded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Second Way:**

```
Button myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
       call();     
    }
});
```

Comment: this is what i have :  Button radioButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_screen);                 RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

Comment: @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
                call();
            }
        });
        radioButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    }
    private void call()
    {
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("0723263921"));
        try{
            startActivity(in);
        }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your Activity not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Answer (score 1):

create `RadioGroup` and then `RadioButton` inside `RadioGraoup`

```
RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.yourRadioGroup);        
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        RadioButton callRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);

        //gettext you write with radiobutton
        String  dailString=callRadioButton.getText().toString();

        //check if you select the radio button
        if(dailString.trim().equals("dailnumber"){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789")); 
            startActivity(intent); 
        }else{ 
        // do action with other android button
        }
    } 
});
```

**Edited**

***java code***

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.btn_radio_group);
        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton callRadioButton=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);

                //gettext you write with radiobutton
                String  dailString=callRadioButton.getText().toString();

                //check if you select the radio button
                if(dailString.trim().equals("Dail")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    // do action with other android button
                }
            }
        });
    }
}



***XML***
```

***minifest***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.radiogroupPermistion">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***XML***'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/btn_radio_group"
        >

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dail"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/dail_id"
            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/otherid"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

***Edit 2***

**Button Listener**

***java code***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button dailnumber = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_call_number);
    dailnumber.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
                    startActivity(intent);     }});
  }}
```

Comment: i think you does not specify  the action correctly try this

Comment: @RileyB did this work? If yes, how did it work? Your notes could be useful for someone who comes across the same issue in future.

Comment: it crashes. it does not have any error message in the log. i have no idea why because it does not have any errors in the code. i may need the whole code for java class and the xml. help if you can

Comment: in build.gradle make sure that targetSdkVersion 22 , gradle compileSdkVersion 22 in api 23 you have to add permission at run time

Comment: i have done everything to detail but still refuses to run on device(Still no errors on log). Its a Samsung 5, android 4.4.2. Your solution is way too nice, Thank you.  i just don't know where the problem is.

Comment: can you believe it i have same device s5 mini and it working on it. so don't know what is problem in your case

Comment: thanks. hey quick one, what if i changed the radio button to an actual button, when pressed it brings up the dial menu?? would that still work?? if so, how would you recommend i go about it because my whole entire project is waiting for this function to work(this and an email one).

Comment: yeah it will work on button click Depend upon you requirement.

Comment: same requirements, just the button changes from RadioButton to small button and then the phone call function stays the same.

Comment: I saw my mistake. i learned from it. i didn't know the Permissions on android worked like that, mostly the checkPermission one

Comment: glade to know you find your bug