# What's the relationship between the Activity ,Action and Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I fell confused about the relationship between the Activity, Action and Intent?

And also an another question about the `Implicit intents` : for example I want to start this action `ACTION_CALL` to make a phone call,obviously,  this is an Implicit intent, so I should write like this `Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);`

But I should also need to set the data. Here is my question : How can I know what's the uri looks like? What's the schema?Please just don't tell the simple answer.How do you know that? Is there any API I should look for? And I know in the manifest `<data android:scheme="xxxxx"/>` So where is the manifest about the action or activity `Intent.ACTION_CALL`? I can't find it.

Comment: Read this for your second question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5404269/4350275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activity - It says, from where to where you want to send message e.g: from Activity A to Activity B.

Action - It says, what this message means e.g: Open a URL in webview or make a call etc.

Intent - It says, how to transfer the message and other extra information e.g: directly through explicit intent or indirectly by selecting from multiple options through implicit intent.